# How does an ICal need to be formatted for gmail to automatically add it to your calendar?

Tags: gmail, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I've been jacking around with iCal and email and through some fiddling, I've managed to get gmail to recognize that I do, in fact, have an iCal file embedded in the message. So it looks something like this:
[image: Header of email on gmail]

This is accomplished by adding a third portion to the multipart email that looks something like:

```
--B_ALT_51b091604704b
Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//My Company LLC//My Reminder System//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:2201@example.com
DTSTAMP:20130606T134048Z
ORGANIZER;CN="Robb Nixon":MAILTO:robb.nixon@motorsolutions.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=
 TRUE;CN=Robb Nixon;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:robb.nixon@motorsolutions.com
DTSTART:20130608T120000Z
DTEND:20130608T130000Z
SUMMARY:Follow-Up: Allan Chappell ("New Template")
DESCRIPTION:Subject Line: "New Template"\nDate Sent: "June 6\, 2013 @ 8:40 
 AM CDT\nRecipients:\n  TO:  Allan Chappell (------------------)\,\n    \n
 Email Copy:\n\nDear Allan\,\n\nAn Introduction\n\nMy Body\n\nNext Steps\n\n
 Robb Nixon\nWeb Developer\nSalve Solutions\nmotorsolutions.com\n\n\n\n
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Note, this is an example with some of the values changed... my real invite follows the folding rules to the letter. Also note that my gmail email address would be in the place of robb.nixon@motorsolutions.com as well, so in theory gmail should know that I am the organizer of the event.

When someone sends me an invite via gmail, I instead get the following:
[image: Has Yes No Maybe]

Notice that it has "Going? Yes Maybe No" and the item is automatically added to my calendar. as it arrives to my email without having to hit the "Add to Calendar".

Does anyone know what I'm missing to make this happen for my iCal files? Or is it a Gmail thing where they recognize it's from them and go ahead and automatically add it to your calendar.

Comment: Where you able to find the solution to this?

Comment: I have been trying to find information about how to structure the email to do this. Would you mind sharing it if you can were to find it?

Answer (score 2):

Your iCalendar stream is missing a METHOD:REQUEST property in the VCALENDAR object (i.e. below the PRODID but before the BEGIN:VEVENT.

Gmail may also get confused by the fact that you are also the organizer of this meeting.

Comment: Good call on the METHOD:REQUEST. Got it already actually yesterday. I'll check out the organizer idea... see if that gets me any ground.